# rails3 nested includes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there a proper way to write this, or am I approaching this wrong? I need to do a nested include. I found [This Link](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/beauty-nested-include-option) but it doesn't seem to work.

```
def show
    @showring = Ring.includes(:stones => :upcharges, :variations).find(params[:id])
end
```

I have 3 tables...
Rings which has_many stones
Stones which has_many upcharges

Models:

```
class Ring < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stones
end

class Stone < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :upcharges  
  belongs_to :ring  
end

class Upcharge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stone
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def show
    @showring = Ring.includes([{:stones => :upcharges}, :variations]).find(params[:id])
end
```

Added some brackets :)

Getting all upcharges :

```
@showring.stones.each do |s|
  s.upcharges #Do whatever you need with it
end
```

Option 2 : Declare a `has_many :through`

```
class Ring < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stones
  has_many :upcharges, :through => :stones
end
```

Then in the view :

```
<%= @showring.upcharges.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Ok, it doesn't error in the controller, so i think it may be working. but in my view (JSON) i get undefined method `upcharges' for #&lt;ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fe12dc2b350&gt;

Comment: That's because you have to iterate over `@showring.stones`. It's a collection, therefore you can't call `.upcharges` on it directly. I edited my answer with an example

Comment: thanks. i will try that. i thought the .to_json automatically iterated over the collection...

Comment: Yeah but what were you trying to do? `@showring.stones.upcharges` ? You can't call an association directly on the array returned by a has_many association.

Comment: in my show.json.erb I have:  "upcharges" : <%= @showring.stones.upcharges.to_json.html_safe %>

Comment: Yes, you can't do that. And it's not the .to_json that causes the error. You can only access an association on a model object. `@showring.stones` returns an Array of objects. You have to go through each to call the other association `upcharges`.

Comment: Edited my answer to implement this with a :through if you want

Comment: ok. But i have "stones" : <%= @showring.stones.to_json.html_safe %> in the same JSON view, and that renders fine. it's only once i add in the upcharges.to_json where it stops working. i thought that was odd.

Comment: I was considering doing a has_many, through as well... maybe i'll give that a shot. seemed like the proper way to do this anyway. what do you think?

Comment: Yeah but you can't call a has_many association from the result of another has_many association. You can't call it because it returns an Array of object. `to_json` is not the problem here, your error tells you `undefined method upcharges`

Comment: thank you. i was thinking that was the problem, but wasn't 100% sure. You rock.

Comment: Yes it makes sense to use a :through in this case